# Item Response Theory vs Rasch Model

Tags: mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, model, item-response-theory, item-analysis

1) What's the difference between Item Response Theory and Rasch model?

2) What's the pros and cons between them?

To me, they seem to be very similar as in they both analyze the performance of students answer questionnaires.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Rasch model is a specific model under a very large umbrella term that is Item Response Theory. See for example the [wiki on IRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Item_response_theory#The_Rasch_model) which specifies the Rasch model as the 1 parameter IRT model